# Regex to replace ( ) with [ ] around function arguments

Tags: python, regex

So I have this huge math expressions stored in a string that I got out of SymPy, and I'm trying to format it so that I can use it in Mathematica.

I want to change everything that looks like `'sin(arg)'` to `Sin[arg]` but I also need to make it work for cosine. `arg` can be any of these: `theta1`, `theta2`, `theta3`, `theta4`, `theta5`.

There are a ton of other parentheses in the string that I DON'T want to replace, so it needs to only effect `sin` and `cos` brackets.

For `S = "cos(theta1)"` I've tried:

```
S = S.replace("cos", "Cos")
S = S.replace("sin", "Sin")
S = re.sub(r"Sin|Cos(\()theta1|theta2|theta3|theta4|theta5", "[", S)
S = re.sub(r"Sin|Cos\(theta1|theta2|theta3|theta4|theta5(\))", "]", S)
```

And `S` becomes:

```
'[)'
```

I thought using the parentheses around the `\(` and `\)` would mean it only replaces those specific groups, but apparently not. Is there some function other than `re.sub` that I should be using?

P.S. Is there any way to squash the `sin -> Sin` replacement into the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def replacer(m):
    return m.group(1).capitalize()+"["+m.group(2)+"]"

re.sub("([a-z]+)\(([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)\)",replacer,"cos(Theta1)")
```

I guess ... maybe ...

Answer (score 1):

Given that your only arguments can be `theta1` through `theta5`, you can simply do the replacement

```
sin\((theta[1-5])\)
```

with

```
Sin[\1]
```

and

```
cos\((theta[1-5])\)
```

with

```
Cos[\1]
```

The `\1` is a backreference, taking it value from the first matched parenthesized group in the original string, in this case your argument.

But I'd go with Joran's answer.

Comment: Ah, several approaches are popping up. What would Guido do?

Comment: I'll have to play around with those backreferences. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = 'sin (theta1)'
    regex = (
        r'(sin|cos)'     # group # 1: sin or cos
        r'\s*'           # zero or more spaces
        r'\('            # opening bracket
        r'\s*'           # zero or more spaces
        r'(theta[1-5])'  # group #2 with your parameter
        r'\s*'           # zero or more spaces
        r'\)'            # closing bracket
        r'\s*'           # zero or more spaces
    )

    result = re.sub(regex, r'\1[\2]', test, ).capitalize()
    print(result)
```

Comment: But this capitalizes the `theta`s into `Theta`s

Comment: You're right, have to fix that... Fixed with `capitalize` method instead of `title`. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, `s/title/capitalize` was the ticket. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can specify parts of the pattern that will not be consumed (replaced) with look behinds `(?<=...)` and lookaheads `(?=...)`:

```
S = "cos(theta1)"

S = S.replace("cos","Cos").replace("sin","Sin")

S = re.sub(r"(?<=Sin|Cos)\((?=theta1|theta2|theta3|theta4|theta5)", "[", S)
S = re.sub(r"(?<=(Sin|Cos)\[(theta1|theta2|theta3|theta4|theta5))\)", "]", S)

assert S == 'Cos[theta1]'
```

Comment: Ok, so `?<=` and `?=` inside a capture group tells `re.sub` to ignore the group, but is that only used when you're gonna throw out everything not in a lookahead/behind group?

Comment: The pattern is basically "this single bracket only if preceded by ... and followed by ..." So it is only technically matching the one character, I'm not really sure how to use it other then this but I'm fairly sure that other uses exist.